# how to get the user details using jwt authentication in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, jwt

I am trying to get the user details using JWT token authentication. I am able to get them using BasicAuthentication and JsonWebToken authentication. I am trying to get the details using JWT .

```
class PermissionView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [BasicAuthentication,JSONWebTokenAuthentication]

    def get(self, request,format=None):
        data = {
            'username': request.user.username,
            'password':request.user.password,

        }
        return Response(data)
```

urls:

```
url(r'^api-token/$', obtain_jwt_token),
```

output:
1) generating the token
[image]

2) getting the user details using Basic Authentication and JsonWebTokenauthentication]
[image]

I am trying to get the user details or authenticate the user details using JWT token. Help would be appreciated?

Comment: Why do you want to get users password? I think you are missing self, so it would look like self.request.user.username

Answer (score 0):

Let us revisit JWT in Django flow to understand something:

1. user requests a token from url api-token-auth with his username and password.
2. jwt authenticates the user and returns a token for you to use afterwards (this is done for us by the JWT framework)
3. next when you send the token the JWT authentication class will authenticate the token for you and populate the request with user information you want so that you can use them later in your views.

Conclusion: you will find the user who is currently requesting your API in the request object as `request.user`.

Comment: My user is always anonymous with JWT authentication when I use `request.user` in my view even after including the middleware described here: https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/issues/45 
How did you setup your middleware? Anything special required to have hte `request.user` populated? Thanks!

Comment: nothing special for middleware setup. I do not understand what is the difference between JsonWebToken authentication (the one you say you did) and JWT Authentication in your point of view. basically JWT stands for json web token. I only use post request to authenticate a user with username and password, I then save the token returned from request, and add this token in the header of later requests, that all what it took for me to setup my project to work.